# How to align in "rubber" layout with narrow screens?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have header and page (both in wrappers). Page consists of a left menu and a content. I use div-layout. And I want the following:

1. Header wrapper and page wrapper fill all the screen width, but its content (header and page themselves) be in the specific width boundaries (max and min),
2. The following behaviour in the cases of wide and narrow screen:

wide screen: it is all OK:

[image: wide screen]

narrow screen: it is all OK - wrappers overlaid by their content, and horizontal scroll appears; after scroll to right I can see the rest content within its surroundings (header and page)

[image: narrow screen good]

But actually I have this: after scroll to right I can see only the rest content but not its surroundings!

[image: narrow screen bad]

How to fix it and make it looks like on the second image?

Example (make result window narrower to see the bad case): http://jsfiddle.net/WxaB3/9/.

HTML:

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <b>header</b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="leftMenu">
                <b>leftMenu</b>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <b>ContentContentContentContent</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#header-wrapper, #page-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}

#header-wrapper{
    background: LightCoral;
}

#page-wrapper{
    background: DeepSkyBlue;
}

#header, #page{
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#header{    
    background: LightPink;
}

#page{
    background: LightBlue;
}

#leftMenu{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
}

#content{
    margin-left: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on what the purpose of the layout. If it is the message form on the forum - it must support some sort of cutting, wrapping or hiding content. If it is the page created by administrator or programmer - the layout must be able to treat the content in the right way. And many other cases. Well, it all boils down to moderation of content or correcting of layout design.

In this particular case the layout behaves right. Despite of page element have enough max-width to hold the entire content, it turns wrong when the window of the browser becomes narrower because of the parent container of the page becomes narrower also. To prevent it I had to limit the min-width of the page element or its parent container to the value sufficient to hold the content. So I just add "min-width: 340px;" to the wrappers or to the main element. Or I just increase the min-width property of the page element itself. And as the case I have to keep track of the width of the content of the content element - content moderation again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the overflowing children on your wrapper DIVs. I added `overflow: hidden;` to the `#header-wrapper, #page-wrapper` CSS. See jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WxaB3/10/

> ***Overflow CSS Property*** 
> Generally, the content of a block box is confined to the content edges of the box. In certain cases, a box may
>   overflow, meaning its content lies partly or entirely outside of the
>   box, e.g.:
>
> 1. A line cannot be broken, causing the line box to be wider than the
>      block box. A block-level box is too wide for the containing block.
>      This may happen when an element's 'width' property has a value that
>      causes the generated block box to spill over sides of the containing
>      block.
> 2. An element's height exceeds an explicit height assigned to
>      the containing block (i.e., the containing block's height is
>      determined by the 'height' property, not by content height).
> 3. A descendant box is positioned absolutely, partly outside the box.
>      Such boxes are not always clipped by the overflow property on their
>      ancestors; specifically, they are not clipped by the overflow of any
>      ancestor between themselves and their containing block.
> 4. A descendant box has negative margins, causing it to be positioned partly outside
>      the box.
> 5. The 'text-indent' property causes an inline box to hang off
>      either the left or right edge of the block box.
>
> Whenever overflow occurs, the 'overflow' property specifies whether a
>   box is clipped to its padding edge, and if so, whether a scrolling
>   mechanism is provided to access any clipped out content.

> ***Overflow:hidden;*** 
>  This value indicates that the content is clipped and that no scrolling user interface should be provided to
>   view the content outside the clipping region.

Reference:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html

Comment: Except this, well, hides the overflow. Meaning you can't read it. Meaning that the page looks nice, but is useless. In the OP's version, at least the page is usable, although less than ideally formatted.

Comment: No, the content of the page is "ContentContentContent", isn't it? The left menu is just the div that says LeftMenu - it'll grow vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But either way it doesn't matter. He set widths and max-width on DIVs, so that's why it's not completely responsive. His code is sloppy as hell.

Comment: If you know why his background colors are getting clipped (as you disparagingly imply), perhaps you should change your answer to that? Also, if you think the OP's code is sloppy, you've led a sheltered existence.

Comment: I fixed the clipping...the text he has (which is dummy text) is not being responsive because it's a long single line. I'm not going to rewrite his code. Clearly he gave us this gibberish as an example. And sheltered? Huh? Why not write your own answer instead of trolling...

Comment: I found your solution as one of the bad choice. But it is also my fault - the actual problem is my bad design. And thank you for put my thoughts on the right way. I wrote my own answer.